# Setting Samba Share HDD Space available to Win10

Tags: centos, samba

moving this question from ServerFault... Might be more appropriate here.

Little bit new to Linux/Centos7 working with Samba.

I have a XFS LVM (spanned over 2 internal harddrives).

```
Filesystem                    1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root        52403200 50467380    1935820  97% /
devtmpfs                        3961956        0    3961956   0% /dev
tmpfs                           3977436       80    3977356   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           3977436     9208    3968228   1% /run
tmpfs                           3977436        0    3977436   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home       427041048    90040  426951008   1% /home
/dev/sdc1                        508588   216820     291768  43% /boot
tmpfs                            795488        8     795480   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                            795488       48     795440   1% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/lvm_pool-Storage 2928843508    32976 2928810532   1% /run/media/root/e6072a3d-a27d-4b7f-9b77-a4594950d5e5
```

Successfully set up Samba Shares which I can easily access from Windows 10, but of the 3TB storage on the HDD, the share on Windows can only see 50GB.

Wondering if there is a setting in Centos7 (64-bit) to allow my Samba Share to make the whole 3TB available to my windows share?

Testparm Dump if relevant (which I assume it most certainly is)

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    netbios name = MYECOM-MEDIA
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    security = USER
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    hosts allow = 127. 192.168.


[Plex-Storage]
    path = /mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

Comment: It seems you do not have mounted `/dev/mapper/lvm_pool-Storage` to `/mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage`, which is the exported folder.

Comment: The HDD is mounted to /mnt/hdd. Is that not the best way to do it? I can see the folders in Win10, just the size is limited to 50GB

Comment: Seems to be mounted to `/dev/mapper/lvm_pool-Storage on /run/media/root/e6072a3d-a27d-4b7f-9b77-a4594950d5e5 type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota,uhelper=udisks2)`

Comment: OK so i changed the Samba path to `/run/media/root/e6072a3d-a27d-4b7f-9b77-a4594950d5e5` and i can now see 2.72TB of space.

For future reference, Thomas, could you tell me the correct command to mount the location correctly to /mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage or better yet /Plex-Storage?? if you can post as an answer, not a comment, then i can give you a big tick!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be to keep the Samba configuration as it is and mount the LVM to the path configured in Samba.

```
[Plex-Storage]
    path = /mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

Then create the mount point and add it to your `/etc/fstab`, so it is mounted on reboot.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage
echo "/dev/mapper/lvm_pool-Storage  /mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage       xfs defaults            1 2" >> /etc/fstab
```

After that, reboot or execute the following commands.

```
systemctl stop smb
umount /dev/mapper/lvm_pool-Storage
mount /mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage
systemctl stop smb
```

Answer (score 0):

All solved thanks to Thomas

Added remount to FSTAB into the right place with permissions set accordingly